# Password verification with regex does not work in my shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to use a regex to check a password that meets the requirements: one upper case, one lower case, one number and special character at least. When I run this code:

```
regexpassword='^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z0-9@$!%*#?&]{6,}$'

echo -n "Enter the password: "
read -s password
while [[ ! $password =~ $regexpassword ]]; 
do 
    somestuff...
```

Even though the password meets the requirements, it activates the loop.

EDIT: Because it's a PCRE regex, it's not working well. I used `grep -P` and now is working good!

Comment: Your regex is more like PCRE than ERE which is the regex engine that works with `=~`

Comment: @Jetchisel Oh, I see. Didnt't know the ERE thing. Thanks!

Comment: @DeiviiD add an answer instead of edit the question

Comment: @Jetchisel I try it, but I don't the option...